# How can I use the .htaccess file to rewrite URL's for a subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm currently using this to make my URLs look pretty:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I finally got it to work (I'm very new to this), but now I need this to work for a 'subsite' that is sitting in a subdirectory of the mainsite. Instead of rewriting https://example.com/index.php it needs to rewrite https://example.com/sub/index.php

I tried some things like changing the RewriteBase and RewriteRule, but with no succes.

Just to be sure, I should be able to put another .htaccess in a subdirectory and expect it to rewrite the urls for example.com/sub, right?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I added exceptions to the main .htaccess like so:
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -Indexes

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/controle|/controle/|/voting|/voting/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, I still do not know what to put into the .htaccess in the subdir, the same one does not work and I tried changing things like
`RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /subdir1/`

Comment: _“Just to be sure, I should be able to put another .htaccess in a subdirectory and expect it to rewrite the urls for example.com/sub, right?”_ - no, not as long as you root level .htaccess catches those requests already - then they will get rewritten by that one already. So you would need to add an exception to those rewrites, that they leave anything stating with `sub/` alone.

Comment: I will add the exceptions, thanks!

Do you also know what I should change to make this .htaccess work for sub/ after I added the exceptions to the root .htaccess file?

Comment: When you added the exception, then pretty much the same thing should work placed inside a .htaccess in the sub folder as well. You can of course also add this on the root level directly (if you want) - match any request paths that start with `sub/` first then and rewrite those to `sub/index.php`, and do the stuff for the root level after that.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code in there, properly formatted, in comments that is hard to read.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question!

Comment: So what happens now, when you try and request something non-existing from the sub folder? Do you get a 404, or does your root level rewriting catch it, despite the added exceptions?

Comment: @CBroe By default, the mod_rewrite directives in the `/subdirectory/.htaccess` file would completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the root `.htaccess` file. No exceptions necessary.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f` this condition will never be met .  You can not check if the `index.html` file exist like this as the `{REQUEST_FILENAME}` already contains full requested file path that is relative to server root.   If you really want to check if this file exists then use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just to be sure, I should be able to put another `.htaccess` in a subdirectory and expect it to rewrite the urls for `example.com/sub`, right?

Yes. The mod_rewrite directives in the `/subdir/.htaccess` file will, by default, completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent/root `.htaccess` file. However, you will need to redefine the `ErrorDocument` directives in order to override the root.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
> ```

To clarify, with these two conditions are you wanting to occasionally serve the `index.html` or `index.php` (DirectoryIndex) document from a requested subdirectory, instead of routing the request to `/index.php` in the document root? In this case it would be more common (and marginally more optimal) to simply check that the request does not map to a directory instead (ie. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`). Unless there are some physical subdirectories that you want to route to `/index.php` in the document root?

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
> RewriteRule . index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

These directives could be simplified slightly - and this will help you if you want to apply the same directives to the subsite in `/subdir` (and serve `/subdir/index.php` instead).

Remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely. The relative *susbtitution* string, ie. `index.php`, will then be relative to the directory where the `.htaccess` file is located (or *inherited*).

You also don't need the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112602/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters Stack for more information on this: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary

So, the above can be written:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

(And note my comment above about replacing the two conditions with a directory check instead.)

Now, you could simply copy the exact *same* directives into the `/subdir/.htaccess` file and these will now route requests to `/subdir/index.php` instead, overriding the mod_rewrite directives in the parent.

No need to copy `Options -Indexes`, unless you want to change this option.

OR, if you want to apply the exact same directives (but in relation to the `/subdir`) you could simply enable mod_rewrite inheritance in the `/subdir/.htaccess` file. For example:

```
# /subdir/.htaccess

ErrorDocument 403 /subdir/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /subdir/404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

The effect of `RewriteOptions Inherit` is to essentially "copy" the mod_rewrite directives from the parent config, ie. `/.htaccess` in the root, behind the directives in the current `/subdir/.htaccess` file. It is important to clarify that the directives are "copied", they are not run in-place as if in the root `/.htaccess` file.